# How to compile and link a C/C++ shared object library in the right way?

Tags: c++, regex, shared-libraries, fpic

I have developed a C++ class which reads in a text file and store some information in provate variables. To parse the file, I use regex library. During compilation there is an error I can't understand.
First I make a shared object library for my class. Afterwards I try to compile the test program. Here the error occurs: undefined reference to std::regex_iterator...

I do the compilation with the following commands on a unix machine:

`g++ -c -fpic -m64 -std=c++11 Foo.h Foo.cpp`

`g++ -shared -m64 -std=c++11 -o libFoo.so Foo.o`

`g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -I. -L. -lFoo -o camelTest Foo.h main.cpp`

To reproduce the error, here is a small example:
[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwgtu5rfrnalpn8/try.zip)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you sure your C++ library supports regex?

Comment: You need to use GCC 4.9 to get `<regex>` support

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? GCC haven't supported the regular expressions in the standard library until quite recently.

Comment: Try Boost.Regex or Boost.Xpressive.

Comment: I do not know if regex is supported by C++, but I think so. The error also occurs when I do not include Foo.h in the last command.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is there a document somewhere explaining the particular implementation strategy of GCC's regexp implementation? I take it that this is a somewhat delicate topic, and users may wish to know about the details before deciding to move a project from their own regexp library to the standard version.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the only notes on the design are on the libstdc++ mailing list, look for posts by Tim Shen who finished the regex implementation

Answer (score 0):

`g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -I. -L. -lFoo -o camelTest Foo.h main.cpp -L%PATH_TO_USED_LIB% -l%NAME_OF_LIB%`

If your lib is libregexp, then `%NAME_OF_LIB% == regexp`

The idea is:

Flag `-L`(uppercase) tells gcc **where** your libs are.

Flag `l`(lowercase) tells gcc **which** library should gcc link to your application.

Comment: I thought that the regex lib is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH located.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Comment: if version of your gcc is lower than 4.9.0 then there is bug(regexp functionality is **not** implemented: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631